# Marshaled Ruby Object MIME Type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm attempting to build an API that can return a marshaled Ruby object and I was wondering if there is a MIME type for such an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no **common** ruby mime type. (See the [official list](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/index.html) of application mime types)

Per the RFC, you can however use *experimental or private* mime types, by preceding them wiht **X-** so:

`application/x-ruby`

sounds like a good mime type to me.

Cheers